# inner join on temp table unless it is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to do an inner join with a temp table but only if another variable is not NULL? For example I have a user table, and I pass in a string with userid's separated by semicolons. I read this into a temp table, and inner join against the user table, but only if the string of userid's is not null. Otherwise I want to return all the user rows.

stored proc has a variable passed in:

```
@UidList             varchar(max),
```

this is a string of user ids, separated by semicolons.
This is turned into a temp table

```
DECLARE @List TABLE (UserUid uniqueidentifier NOT NULL)
```

then another function converts passed in string to table

```
IF @UidList IS NOT NULL
INSERT INTO @List(UserUid)
SELECT ItemUid
FROM dbo.AFN_ConvertUidListToTable(@UidList)
```

Then I join on users table

```
select * from users 
...
inner join @List on users.userid = @List.UserUid`
```

but if the passed in string @UidList is null then I want to match all rows in the users table.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: *A line of code speaks more than 1000 words*, or how was that phrase again?

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @tmp table (id int)

--insert into @tmp values (1)

Select * from a
where 
(
ID in (Select ID from @tmp)
or 
(Select Count(ID)  from @tmp)=0
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1a22/10

Comment: given the question states "but only if the string of userid's is not null" you could probably get away with swapping out the select count...

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is just a case of looking at the userids string and branching?

```
IF @UserIds IS NULL
  select * from users
ELSE
  'stuff involving tempdb
```

Comment: I could branch but I'm trying to keep the code size down. I'm leaving out a lot of detail here. the actual query is sizable and branching the entire query would be inelegant

Comment: fair enough - just be careful that the elegance doesn't cost you too much performance

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @UserCount INTEGER

SELECT @UserCount = COUNT(1) FROM #UserIDList

IF @UserCount > 0
BEGIN
  SELECT UserTable.* FROM UserTable JOIN #UserIDList ON UserTable.ID = #UserIDList.ID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT UserTable.* FROM UserTable
END
```

Comment: I could branch but I'm trying to keep the code size down. I'm leaving out a lot of detail here. the actual query is sizable and branching the entire query would be inelegant

Answer (score 0):

The left join will pick up all records from the users table if @UidList IS NULL:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN @List 
ON @List.UserUid = users.userid
WHERE @List.UserUid IS NOT NULL
OR @UidList IS NULL
```

But if @UidList IS NOT NULL, then we are looking for matches.

Comment: @Joe Here it is pulled into a single statement